# can we train a model in tensorflow2.0 without using keras?

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to write a simple ML code to classify the mnist dataset in tensorflow2.0. I didn't use Keras for now since I just want to use lower API to help me understand how tensorflow works. However, after I defined the cross entropy, It seems impossible to continue. All the tf2.0 optimizers are moved to keras and I don't know how to train a model without keras in tf2.0. Is there a way that we bypass keras in tf2.0?

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models

# Helper libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = datasets.mnist.load_data()

print(train_images.shape)
print(len(train_labels))
print(train_images[1,:,:].shape)

# plt.figure()
# plt.imshow(train_images[0])
# plt.colorbar()
# plt.grid(False)
# plt.show()

# Normalize pixel values to be between 0 and 1
train_images, test_images = train_images / 255.0, test_images / 255.0

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

for i in range(1):
    x = tf.constant(train_images[1,:,:].reshape(784), dtype = tf.float32) 
    x = tf.reshape(x, [1, 784])
    print(tf.shape(x), tf.shape(W))
    # define the model
    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
    print(y)
    # correct labels
    y_ = np.zeros(10)
    y_[train_labels[i]] = 1.0
    y_ = tf.constant(y_, dtype = tf.float32)
    y_ = tf.reshape(y_, [1, 10])
    cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_* tf.math.log(y))
    print(cross_entropy)
        I don't know how to continue from here.
```

Answer (score 1):

Backpropagation-based training of models is totally possible in TensorFlow 2.x without using the keras API. The usage will be centered around the `tf.GradientTape` API and optimizers objects under the `tf.optimizers` namespace.

Your example can be modified as follows. Note that it's a simplistic code meant to illustrate the basic usage in a short code snippet. It's not to illustrate machine learning best practices in TF2.

```py
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = datasets.mnist.load_data()

train_images, test_images = train_images / 255.0, test_images / 255.0

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

@tf.function
def my_model(x):
  # This is a hand-rolled logistic regressor.
  y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
  return tf.nn.softmax(y)

@tf.function
def loss(x, y):
  # This is a hand-rolled categorical cross-entropy loss.
  diff = -(labels * tf.math.log(logits))
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(diff)
  return loss

optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)

for i in xrange(num_steps):

  # A single training step.
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    # This is atypical, in that you would normally want to do this in
    # mini-batches, instead of using all examples in x_train and y_train
    # at once. But again, this is just a simple example.
    loss_value = loss(x_train, y_train)
  gradients = tape.gradient(loss_value, [W, b])
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, [w, b]))
```